# TextAlignment at UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, text-alignment

I know how to align text at UILabel.
But this problem is a bit wired.
All other alignments work such as `NSTextAlignmentJustified`, `NSTextAlignmentNatural`. Only `NSTextAlignmentCenter` does not work to make the text at center.
My UILabel is inserted using StoryBoard.
Then text formatting at UILabel is implemented at program as

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    CustomCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    CGRect frame = cell.cellText.frame;
    frame.size.width = cell.bounds.size.width;
    frame.size.height = cell.bounds.size.height;
    cell.cellText.frame = frame;
    cell.cellText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT"  size:screenRect.size.height*0.0163];
    cell.cellText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    cell.cellText.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cell.cellText.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.cellText.clipsToBounds = YES;
    cell.cellText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.cellText.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];



    if(indexPath.section == 0){
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        cell.cellText.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        if(indexPath.item == 0)
            cell.cellText.text = @"Date";
        else if(indexPath.item == 1)
            cell.cellText.text = @"Age";
        else if(indexPath.item == 2)
            cell.cellText.text = @"Height (cm)";
        else if(indexPath.item == 3)
            cell.cellText.text = @"%le";
        else if(indexPath.item == 4)
            cell.cellText.text = @"Weight (kg)";
        else if(indexPath.item == 5)
            cell.cellText.text = @"%le";
    }
    else if(indexPath.section % 2 == 0 && indexPath.section != 0)
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    else
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];



    return cell;


}
```

Why can't align to center as shown in the picture.
[image]

EDIT:
I changed the UILabel's background as

```
if(indexPath.section == 0){
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        cell.cellText.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.cellText.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        if(indexPath.item == 0)
            cell.cellText.text = @"Date";
        else if(indexPath.item == 1)
            cell.cellText.text = @"Age";
        else if(indexPath.item == 2)
            cell.cellText.text = @"Height (cm)";
        else if(indexPath.item == 3)
            cell.cellText.text = @"%le";
        else if(indexPath.item == 4)
            cell.cellText.text = @"Weight (kg)";
        else if(indexPath.item == 5)
            cell.cellText.text = @"%le";
    }
```

The updated picture is
[image]

Comment: can you try to set background color of cellText to red or bule to see it's frame?

Comment: check that your frame of label as per @CongTran -- comment is useful for you

Comment: @Cong Tran, I updated in Edit, Thanks

Comment: @batuman could you try to set background color of "Height" item to clear color, and keep background of "Age" item in red. I think it was overlapped when you set frame for it.

Comment: @Cong Tran, let me try. I'll update. Those white vertical lines are from background. I add UILabel on UICollectionViewCell. I don't think they are overlapping.

Comment: could you try to add this line below your set cellText color method cell.cellText.center = cell.center;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the frame for setting the position of the `cellText`. The cell hasn't been laid out in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath` so the frame will be wrong. It's entirely plausible that the frame will be the frame of the last time that cell was reused.

Instead, use AutoLayout to constrain the UILabel to all edges of the cell.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Replace these lines

```
CGRect frame = cell.cellText.frame;
frame.size.width = cell.bounds.size.width;
frame.size.height = cell.bounds.size.height;
cell.cellText.frame = frame;
```

With this code.

```
cell.cellText.center = cell.center;
CGRect frame = cell.cellText.frame;
frame.size.width = cell.bounds.size.width;
frame.size.height = cell.bounds.size.height;
cell.cellText.frame = frame;
```

If you want to use autolayout then just add two constraints two your label.

- Center vertically in container.
- Center horizontally in container.

[image]

Comment: Just to add to your constraints, if you instead pinned the label to the edges, the intrinsic content size of the label would allow for autosizing of the cells (with an estimated item size on the layout). If this is desirable (i.e. you wish the cell to grow with regard to it's title label), then this could be the way to go.